# Access SMS and Whatsapp messages via pc

Tags: lumia, whatsapp, sms

My mother's windows 8 phone has a broken screen which won't respond to any touch input. I would like to access the sms and whatsapp messages so they can be transferred to another phone. Is there an app that can do this or is it possible to access the files via a pc. I can connect via usb connection but I can only see Documents/Pictures/Music/Videos and all the apps available seem to be designed to run on the phone, rather than a pc which isn't possible since the screen is broken.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think that that's not possible

Comment: WhatsApp messages can be backed up from within the app.

Comment: I appreciate they can be backed up within the app, but as the screen is broken and doesn't respond to any touch input, I can't actually access the app. Hence I'm looking for a way to access them via a pc and usb cable.

Comment: yes, you can install Whatsapp on Windows 10 and see messages if phone connected by bluetooth for example